# Change first listbox item style in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I would like to change the style of the first item in a listbox on startup. What method can I use to change this code for an other style for the first item only?

```
    <ListBox x:Name="ListboxNieuws"
             Width="408"
             Margin="0,10,-12,0"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            Tap="StackPanel_Tap">
                    <!--  Replace rectangle with image  -->
                    <Rectangle Width="100"
                               Height="100"
                               Margin="12,0,9,0">
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush x:Name="plaatje" ImageSource="{Binding LineImg}" />
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <StackPanel Width="311">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="title"
                                   FontSize="30"
                                   Text="{Binding LineOne}"
                                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <Line Stretch="Fill"
                              Stroke="White"
                              X1="0"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="time"
                                   Margin="0,0,12,10"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding LineTwo}" />
                        <Image Width="20"
                               Height="20"
                               Margin="-170,-45,0,0"
                               Source="/PostDateIcon.png" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="date"
                                   Margin="85,-37,12,10"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"
                                   Text="{Binding LineThree}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="content"
                                   Text="{Binding LineContent}"
                                   Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Hopefully one of you can help me to change this style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the `ItemTemplateSelector` to apply the template for your item based on your wish...

Have a look on the following link...

- [ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)